# Is not null in EntityFramework query

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0, linq-to-entities

Entity Framework 4.0 code first, C# 4.0.
What is wrong for **is not null** in the code?

```
var query = from c in dbContext.table 
where c.FacilityID == facilityID && c.FilePath is Not null select c;
```

**EDIT:**

Many errors after adding is not null.

One of them is :

> The type or namespace name 'Not' could not be found (are you missing a
>   using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: What error did you get when you ran it?

Answer (score 11):

`Not` is not a keyword in LINQ queries, so you will get the compiler errors. You need to use the inequality operator (`!=`) to check if `FilePath` is not null.

The code below should work for you

```
var query = from c in dbContext.table 
where c.FacilityID == facilityID && c.FilePath != null select c;
```

Comment: Just to clarify what happened here. '!=' is the inequality operator for C#. Similarly 'Is Not' is the inequality operator for Visual Basic.NET. I could see how a person might get confused since much of the .NET framework documentation shows both languages.

Comment: @Mr.Young The VB inequality operator (compares two object reference variables) is 'IsNot' and not 'Is Not'.